# Can file copy failures be caused by file content?

Tags: linux, file-transfer, kde, kde-plasma-5

I was copying some files from my laptop's hard drive on to a USB thumb drive/pen drive/key/stick earlier today, using KDE 5 to do the copy (drag and drop in Dolphin). I encountered a problem: the copy operation would finish the first file and then stop, or at least pause long enough that it exceeded my patience. It never advanced to the second file.

A friend who was present at the time suggested that this could be caused by CRC errors, namely that there's something about the *content of the file itself* that means it's never going to pass some CRC check that Linux or KDE is doing behind the scenes. This sounds fishy to me. Not that there may be "hidden" checksums or other verification procedures built into the copy operation at sum level (:-P); that's totally reasonable. But I would expect these verification procedures to be able to cope with *any* sequence of bytes whatsoever, because the content of a file can be literally anything. Right?

In short, what I'm asking is this: if a file copy operation fails, is there *any possible way* that failure could be caused by the *content* of the copied file, and not by a hardware error nor a bug in the software that handles copying?

I suspect the real problem in my case was a hardware error on the USB drive, but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: You are correct, there is no content that could cause failure of a copy operation in the manner you describe.  However, you may have misinterpreted what your friend was saying.  If verification is happening, the source and destination files are being compared.  An error would mean that the file wasn't faithfully copied (for some reason independent of file content), not that the source file contained content that was already in error or was impossible to copy.

Comment: @fixer1234 Yeah, that occurred to me. If I had misinterpreted what my friend said, though, there's no question ;-) Perhaps you could post an answer?

Answer (score 1):

This may be a case where both of you are correct.  To quote from *Cool Hand Luke*, ["What we've got here is failure to communicate"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2f-MZ2HRHQ).

You are correct, there is no content that could cause failure of a copy operation in the manner you describe.

However, you may have misinterpreted what your friend was saying. If verification is happening, the error stems from the source and destination files being compared. An error would mean that the file wasn't faithfully copied (for some reason independent of file content), not that the source file contained content that was already in error or was impossible to copy.